# Continuous composed with differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

If $f(x)$ is $C^\infty$ and $g(x)$ is bounded and continuous does that imply that $f(g(x))$ is differentiable

Comment: If $f(x)$ is $C^\infty$...where?

Answer (score 2):

Take $f(x) = x$ for all $x$. Is any bounded $g$ differentiable ?